# WordPress криво работает PrettyPhoto, почему? На одной странице отрабатывает верно, на другой криво

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Вот линк на страницу с работающим скриптом полностью: `artkravits.com/exhibitions/#!`
А тут, в галлереи, нет списка внизу картинки для навигации: `artkravits.com/art-gallery/#!`
Сайт на WordPress. Плагин чужой ( PrettyPhoto ), уже потратил пол дня, проблема со скриптом, он подключаеться и отрабатывает во втором случае частично, без списка ul->li для навигации по слайдеру. 
Пробовал подключить в шаблон скрипт отключив старый:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
(function(e){....
 });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.vc_grid-item').clik(function($){
(function(e){....
 });
  </script>
```

---

Все работает так же как при подклчюении стандартного скрипта.
Шаблон для вывода картинок одинаковый ( только стили немного разные ). 
Скрипты тоже одинаковые. Почему генерит там навигацию ul а там - нет? 
Я со скриптами мало работал, с чем может быть связано подобное поведение?
( он не генерирует список ul в слайдере ).

Comment: не `clik`  а `click` , да и не увидел ни на одной странице из ссылок никакой `ul` навигации, что вы имеете в виду, опишите подробней? Скрипт не работает ни на одной из представленных страниц.

Comment: @Blacknife: класс .pp_gallery  по нажатию на фото, запускаеться js код плагина PrettyPhoto, он генерирует попап. Там идет слайдер, и навигация в нем идет фотографии внизу слайдера, собственно во тета навигация и идет в ul-> li списке. ( возможно вы смотрели на сайте когда я тестировал и убирал временно скрипт вот еще раз, рабочая ссылка http://artkravits.com/exhibitions/#!
ломаная, где нет списка http://artkravits.com/art-gallery/#!

Comment: покажите скрипт инициализации рабочей галереи полностью

Comment: + скорее всего в скрипте есть ограничение на вывод превьюшек при большом кол-ве фотографий, поробуйте снизить их кол-во до менее чем 80, или в скрипт инициализации добавьте параметр `overlay_gallery: true`

Comment: да, вы абсолютно правы! Спасибо)